# DataFrame change doesn't save when iterating

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, calculated-columns

I am trying to read a certain DF from file and add to it two more columns containing, say, the year and the week from other columns in DF. When i apply the code to generate a single new column, all works great. But when there are few columns to be created, the change does not apply. Specifically, new columns are created but their values are not what they are supposed to be.

I know that this happens because i first set all new values to a certain initial string and then change some of them, but I don't understand why it works on a single column and is "nulled" for multiple columns, leaving only the latest column changed... Help please?

```
tbl =  pd.read_csv(file).fillna('No Fill')
date_cols = ['Col1','Col2']
for i in range(len(date_cols)):
    tmp_col_name = date_cols[i] + '_WEEK'
    tbl[tmp_col_name] = 'No Week'   
    bad_ind = list(np.where(tbl[date_cols[i]] == 'No Fill')[0])        
    tbl_ind = range(len(tbl))
    for i in range(len(bad_ind)): 
        tbl_ind.remove(bad_ind[i])
    tmp = pd.to_datetime(tbl[date_cols[i]][tbl_ind])        
    tbl[tmp_col_name][tbl_ind] = tmp.apply(lambda x: str(x.isocalendar()[0]) + '+' + str(x.isocalendar()[1]))
```

If I try the following lines, disregarding possible "empty data values", everything works...

```
tbl =  pd.read_csv(file).fillna('No Fill')
date_cols = ['Col1','Col2']
for i in range(len(date_cols)):
    tmp_col_name = date_cols[i] + '_WEEK'
    tbl[tmp_col_name] = 'No Week'   
    tmp = pd.to_datetime(tbl[date_cols[i]])        
    tbl[tmp_col_name] = tmp.apply(lambda x: str(x.isocalendar()[0]) + '+' + str(x.isocalendar()[1]))
```

it has to do with not changing all data values, but i don't understand why the change does not apply - after all, before the second iteration begins, the DF seems to be updated and then `tbl[tmp_col_name] = 'No Week'` for the second iteration "deletes" the changes made in the first iteration, but only partially - it leaves the new column created but filled with 'No Week' values...

Comment: You are performing [chained indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) which may or may not work, in your case it doesn't work you need to use the new `loc`, `iloc` or `ix` accessors to set the data.

Comment: Also what you're doing can be vectorised, I think can you post raw input data, what your initial df lookd like and what the expected output is and explain what your code is doing

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to @EdChum! Performing chained indexing may or may not work. In case of creating new multiple columns and then filling in only some of their values, it doesn't work. More precise, it does work but only on the last updated column. Using loc, iloc or ix accessors to set the data works. In case of the above code, to make it work, one needs to cast the tbl_ind into np.array, using `tbl[col_name[j]].iloc[np.array(tbl_ind)] = tmp.apply(lambda x: x.year)`
Many thanks and credit for the answer to @EdChum.